# Open web service explorer with http error 500 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse version **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers** Luna Release.

When I click ***Launch the Web Service Explorer*** under the ***Run*** menu, the explorer that eclipse has in its own turns out to be **HTTP ERROR: 500**. Don't it be a web page instead of reminding me of the error?

I do not know how to solve it.

I find out this problem when I try to publish my first web project with Tomcat installed in the eclipse. However it shows the http error 500.:(

Hope someone can help me~

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A 500 error is for an internal server error.  Is something causing an error within your web project?  I'm not certain I completely understand the nature of your question.

Comment: @mattingly890 I find that there may be some problems with my eclipse actually...Since if you run a web service explorer which is in the Menu "Run" in j2ee branch, there should be a web page. However, in my eclipse there turns out to be http error 500. And I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to start eclipse from the command line and use the -vm option, e.g.

```
./eclipse -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You will see a warning from eclipse to select a different vm if one or more installed features depends on jdk8, e.g. Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.  You can click the cancel button at this point.

You can also edit `eclipse.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

When I uninstalled the Java 8 SDK and used the Java 7 SDK the Web Services Explorer ran normally.